# What is the difference between separate tables and a single table with a tag

Tags: database, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE foo_baz(
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    value1 REAL NOT NULL,
    value2 REAL NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE foo_bar(
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    value1 REAL NOT NULL,
    value2 REAL NOT NULL
)
```

versus

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    value1 REAL NOT NULL,
    value2 REAL NOT NULL,
    ty int NOT NULL
)
```

I only need to iterate over (time, value1, value2) I don't need to do any joints between tables. I just want to iterate over those values as fast as possible. Is there a difference between

```
 SELECT time, value1, value2 FROM foo WHERE ty = 0;
 SELECT time, value1, value2 FROM foo WHERE ty = 1;
 ..
```

and

```
SELECT time, value1, value2 FROM foo_baz;
SELECT time, value1, value2 FROM foo_bar;
```

I am looking for something like this

```
struct Foo {
    Time time;
    float value1;
    float value2;
}

HashMap<int, Array<Foo>>
```

Are [multicolumn indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) the feature that I am looking for?

Comment: Your table `foo` is what I would use in practice.  If you use separate tables, only 2 in this case, it could lead to a design problem later on if there end up being more than two types.  In that case, you would have to keep adding new tables, and your queries would become cluttered as you union together everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a difference, even if you set up indexes right, it still has to go at least over the index (in the case of `foo`). But in practice I think this shouldn't be a performance bottleneck, the difference should be really small.

Anyway, if performance is really that crucial, you might want to use **PARTITIONING** = having a master table (like `foo`) and then a partition table for every value of `ty`, with check constraints set up on the `ty` column (and of course some good indexes). That way you should be able to get (almost) identical performance as in your separate tables case, because the partitions will physically be separate tables, the only extra thing for the engine will be to check the `check constraint` and decide which partitioned table to use. And you will also keep it all easily usable the same way as in your `foo` table case with the master table.

More info on partitioning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html